# Why RSpecMatchers#have_title return code is green ? in my product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I expected this code to return red because the title part of the view evaluates to "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App". But actually, green was returned.
On the other hand, the title part of the view that the specification expects is "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App". I don't know why this will happen.

application.html.haml is common layout.

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title 
      = full_title(yield(:title))
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    = yield
```

home.html.haml is view content

```
= provide(:title, "Home")
%h1 Sample App
%p
  This is the home page for the
  %a{href: 'https://railstutorial.jp/'} Ruby on Rails Tutorial
  sample application.
```

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
    base_title if page_title.empty?

    page_title + ' | ' + base_title
  end
end
```

spec code

```
RSpec.describe 'static_controller', type: :system do
  before do
    @base_title = 'Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
  end
  describe 'Home' do
    it 'check title' do
      visit root_url
      expect(page).to have_title @base_title.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Capybara RSpec matcher `#have_title` uses Capybara's `#assert_title` under the hood ([source](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers/have_title.rb#L10)).

From [`#assert_title`'s docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/DocumentMatchers#assert_title-instance_method):

> ```
> #assert_title(string, **options) ⇒ true
> ```
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `string (String)` — The string that title should include

Note that is says "include". If you want an exact match, there's an option for that. From the docs:

> **Options Hash (`**options`):**
>
> - `:exact (Boolean)` — default: `false` — When passed a string should the match be exact or just substring

Since the RSpec matcher just passes the options to this `#assert_title` method, you should be able to write the expectation as follows (no need for `#to_s` since `@base_title` is a string):

```rb
expect(page).to have_title(@base_title, exact: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the default behavior of `have_title` is to do a substring match - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/DocumentMatchers:has_title%3F

If you want an exact match pass `exact: true`

expect(page).to have_title(@base_title.to_s, exact: true)